# Removing items in an arraylist from another arraylist in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, arrays, vb.net, t-sql, arraylist

I am writing a VB.NET webforms site, one page of which has to load a list of files into a listbox. It needs to load all PDF and TIF files in a directory that do not have entries in a database. I am doing this successfully at the moment with the following code. Basically, I query the database to get an arraylist of filename entries, then go through each file in the directory, check its name against each entry in the arraylist, and if its name is not in the arraylist, add it to list to bind to the listbox:

```
    Dim category As String = "RFQ"

    'Initialize database connection variables
    Dim sql As String
    Dim query As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim result As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    'Load document list from database
    Dim savedfiles As New ArrayList
    database.Open() 'Open connection to database  
    sql = "SELECT filename FROM fileheaders WHERE [category] = '" & category & "'" 'SQL query to read file header information
    query = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, database) 'Create query to send to database
    result = query.ExecuteReader() 'Execute query
    While result.Read()
        savedfiles.Add(row(result, "filename"))
    End While
    result.Close()
    dbDocscan.Close()


    'The following code section pulls all files from the current file directory.
    Dim filelist = New ArrayList
    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dirName) 'Get directory information
    Dim files As System.IO.FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles() 'Get all files in directory
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each file In files
        If ((file.Extension Like ".pdf") Or (file.Extension Like ".tif")) And Not inArray(savedfiles, file.Name) Then
            filelist.Add(file.Name) 'Add .pdf and .tif files to list of documents
        End If
    Next

    filelist.TrimToSize()
    eltFilelist.DataSource = filelist
    eltFilelist.DataBind() 'Bind document list to listbox
```

Then the inArray function code:

```
Function inArray(arr As ArrayList, str As String) As Boolean
    For Each item In arr
        If TypeOf (item) Is String Then
            If str = item Then
                Return True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Here's the problem: while it works, it seems terribly inefficient. There are around 27,000 files in the directory and around 26,000 file entries in the database. So I am checking each of 27,000 filenames against a list of 26,000 names. Without making this into a combinatorics problem, that's hundreds of millions of string matching statements. Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: This is a good question, but I'd say it's better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've already got an answer, so no use moving it now. But how does the purpose of CodeReview differ from that of StackOverflow?

Comment: I'd say the simplest way to distinguish between the two would be, CodeReview is for code that already works (but may need improvement) whereas StackOverflow is for code that doesn't work yet :)  That's, perhaps oversimplifying it a bit, but sums it up neatly.  I almost didn't recommend it because this question kind of falls in a gray area where it kind of still works on StackOverflow, but it is stretching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an SQL parameter to avoid problems with the category string (e.g. if it had an apostrophe in it a concatenated query string would be broken), get only the files in the directory which have the extensions you're interested in, and you could use LINQ to get the missing files in a simple way:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Function GetMissingFiles(sourceDirectory As String, category As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim missingFiles As New List(Of String)

        Dim filesInDatabase As New List(Of String)

        ' Query the database for the files in the given category'
        Using conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
            conn.Open()
            Dim sqlCmd As String = "SELECT filename FROM fileheaders WHERE [category] = @category"
            Dim query As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlCmd, conn)
            'TODO: change .SqlDbType to what it is in the database.'
            query.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@category", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = category})

            Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = query.ExecuteReader()

            While rdr.Read()
                filesInDatabase.Add(rdr.GetString(0))
            End While

            conn.Close()

        End Using

        'TODO: it could be that filesInDatabase.Count = 0 is valid. Adjust if required.'
        If filesInDatabase.Count > 0 Then
            ' Get the existing files from the given directory.

            ' the extensions we are going to consider
            Dim extensions() As String = {"pdf", "tif"}

            Dim existingFiles As New List(Of String)

            ' get all the filenames (without the path) to consider'
            For Each extn In extensions
                existingFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*." & extn).ToList().Select(Function(p) Path.GetFileName(p)))
            Next

            missingFiles = existingFiles.Except(filesInDatabase).ToList()

        End If

        Return missingFiles

    End Function
    Sub Whatever()
        Dim myMissingFiles As List(Of String)
        Try
            myMissingFiles = GetMissingFiles("C:\temp", "RFQ")
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Inform user it went wrong.'
        End Try

        If myMissingFiles IsNot Nothing AndAlso myMissingFiles.Count > 0 Then
            eltFilelist.DataSource = myMissingFiles
            eltFilelist.DataBind()
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm pretty new to VB.NET, and I wasn't aware of the list class. This should be very useful.

Just a side note on the SQL parameter, I went the easy route with just a variable because the variable is defined by the script without user input, so there's no real room for conflict. Thanks for catching it, though.

I will try your List.Except method, make sure I can get it working, and report back.

Comment: Just an update: I set savedfiles as a List(Of String) and put in all filenames from the database. I set filelist as a List(Of String) and put in all filenames from the directory. Then I set missingfiles as a List(Of String) and set it to filelist.Except(savedfiles).toList() and used it as my listbox.DataSource. Worked perfectly. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: @user1978952 One more tip: if you are making that query to the database a lot and the category name can have a widely varying length, then you should also set the .Length parameter of the SqlParameter to whatever it is set to in the database. SQL Server makes itself a "plan" before it executes a query, and if it sees different lengths for the parameter then it makes a new plan for each length. IME with SQL Server 2008 R2, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ArrayList, use a Dictionary or HashTable to save the file names from your query.

Your inArray function is doing a O(n) table scan for every file found, which is quite slow.

Both Dictionaries and HashTables has a Contains member that will search your file names at a significantly faster rate.